# Will Eclipse + Android Developer Tools plugin work on OS X Yosemite?

Tags: java, android, macos, eclipse

I would like to update my system to the newest 10.10 Yosemite version, but I use quite intensively Eclipse + ADT to develop apps for Android. Does anyone have any experience with running this software on Yosemite (maybe beta version)?

I am asking this question, because I would like to update, but on the other hand I don't want to mess things up with Java and ADT (btw. There were problems and I needed to use workarounds even on Mavericks).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got this error

[image]

I tried updating the Java to the latest Java 8 update 25 but still didn't work.

but after going to the recommended website from apple and download and install it: http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US

it worked just fine again. It was able to start.

It says Java 6. I'm not really sure what other repercussions will be. It's like a downgrade.

i still do have 1.7 in my eclipse compiler though.

[image]

Comment: There are two kavas involved in Eclipse - one is to run Eclipse the other is to compile the code - They can be set differently