# Jetbrains'IDE can't start after upgrading to OS X Yosemite

Tags: macos, java, ide

Yesterday I upgrade my MBP to OSX 10.10 Yosemite, everything went well. But When I try to start Pycharm, it shows me this

[image]

It means "You need to install old Java SE 6 runtime to run Pycharm".

It seems I'm not the only one run into this problem
https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/27854363-IDE-doesn-t-start-after-updating-to-Mac-OS-Yosemite-or-Mavericks

There're some hacks from the link above, but I would like to find an "official way" to solve this. I'm also curious about the cause of this problem.

Thank you!

Comment: Try the solution over here - http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/150873/will-eclipse-android-developer-tools-plugin-work-on-os-x-yosemite

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I found the official solution

Download Java for OS X 2014-001 from [here](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572), install, done :)

Answer (score 9):

You can also solve it by doing the following:

Locate your Installed package (PyCharm or IntelliJ), right click, show package contents

Under contents, open up Info.plist

Locate the JVMOptions dictionary entry, and find the key titled "JVMVersion"

The default value for that key should be "1.6*". change it to "1.6+".

Save it, and re-launch the IDE again.

You should be able to use it without JDK 6 installed.

Comment: True, but Java1.6 has better font rendering on Mac.

Comment: This worked for me! Thank you. I wanted it to work with Java 8 u25 and this did the trick!

Comment: @laike9m, this is perhaps true, but I doubt that there will be further updates for JDK6 on the mac, except for maybe security updates.

Comment: Normally, I'd favor using a newer Java implementation, but, in this case, Jetbrains recommends against this as it will change the file signature on the plist file, and that will prevent further updates to the application, they say.

Comment: Did not work for me, pycharm kept complaining. I went with the old jre 6 now.

Comment: according to the official jetbrains support, "Modifying Info.plist will break the application digital signature and prevent the patch updates. We do not recommend modifying Info.plist file to run under JDK 1.7 or 1.8." https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/27854363-IDE-doesn-t-start-after-updating-to-Mac-OS-Yosemite-or-Mavericks. Use @laike9m's answer.